# Python: how to rename dataframe with column names in tuple?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below

```
   Col1/sum/mean     Col2/sum/mean   Col3/sum/mean
A      1                   2                3
B      4                   5                6
C      7                   8                9
```

I find it annoying to access the column by doing `df[('Col1','sum','mean')]` everytime, is there a way to remove the `sum` and `mean` levels ? Or rename it ?

Comment: basically u want to strip off the sum and mean and just have Col1, col2, col3?

Answer (score 0):

If there are tuples select first value of tuple:

```
df.columns = [x[0] for x in df.columns]
```

If no tuples use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with selecting first value:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('/').str[0]
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3
A     1     2     3
B     4     5     6
C     7     8     9
```

Comment: @sammywemmy - Yes, my answer is if there are tuples

Comment: geez. i missed that. my bad